# How to publish NPM Scoped Packages / NPM scope not found?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I want to start publishing npm packages to a scope.  Do I need to register as a user with the scope as my user name?  Example if I create a package like this:

```
    ole@MKI:~/firstpackage$ npm init

    Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
    save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

    Press ^C at any time to quit.
    name: (firstpackage) @npmtestscope/firstpackage
    version: (1.0.0) 
    description: 
    entry point: (index.js) 
    test command: 
    git repository: 
    keywords: 
    author: 
    license: (ISC) 
    About to write to /home/ole/deletethis/package.json:

    {
      "name": "@npmtestscope/firstpackage",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }


    Is this ok? (yes) 

    ole@MKI:~/firstpackage$ touch README.md
    ole@MKI:~/firstpackage$ npm publish
```

This is the result:

```
npm ERR! 404 Scope not found : @npmtestscope/firstpackage
```

So what do I need to do in order for npm to find the scope?

Comment: In order to create an organization on npm that will allow you to publish packages to your scopes complete steps 1, 2, and 3 on this page: https://www.npmjs.com/docs/orgs/getting-started.html

Comment: if you want @npmtestscope, you must a create a npmtestscope organization https://www.npmjs.com/docs/orgs/

Comment: so it's necessary paying

Comment: Not for public repositories.  I think the only other thing you have to do, besides registering the organization, is use the `--access public` flag when you publish for the first time.

Comment: Organizations on npm can be created here: https://www.npmjs.com/org/create - If you have created your organization, then you can publish your namescoped package using `npm publish --access public`.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer might as well put that as the answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you want to publish a package on npm using the name `@npmtestscope/firstpackage`, you need to make sure that the namespace `@npmtestscope` exists on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). To create that namespace, you need to [create an organization on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/org/create) with the name `npmtestscope`.

After you have created the organization, you can publish your package named `@npmtestscope/firstpackage` by executing `npm publish --access public`.

**Note:** To run `npm publish` for a package that belongs to a npm organization, you need to be logged in on your computer as a member of that organization. You can do that by executing `npm login`. The `npm whoami` command will show you the user name associated with the current login.

Comment: Ah, the login part was the necessary step for me, I was logged in with my old account, I needed to update that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I was having a hard time with this scoped packages stuff!