# Package is not publishing to npm( - Scope not found)

Tags: npm, github-actions, cicd, npm-package, npm-publish

I would like to publish my git repository to npm ,I am using Github Actions publishing
but I get the following error:

```
npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.com/
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.com/@fast-plus%2feslint-config - Scope not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@fast-plus/eslint-config@1.0.74' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@fast-plus/eslint-config",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "ESLint Config",
  "license": "MIT",
  "files": [
    "index.js"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-define-config": "^1.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsonc": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-markdown": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^43.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.1.1",
    "jsonc-eslint-parser": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "yaml-eslint-parser": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.18.0"
  }
}
```

Package can publish to npm

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to publish NPM Scoped Packages / NPM scope not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824012/how-to-publish-npm-scoped-packages-npm-scope-not-found)